# How to make a loop with this array?

Tags: javascript, loops

in Javascript for example I have this array:

```
var ids = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
```

*(The number of objects in the array changes constantly)*

How could I get this result *(a new array)*, and how can I separate it? for example in 3 *(I probably need to make a loop for this)*

```
var urls= ["example.com/?id0=1&id1=2&id2=3", "example.com/?id3=4&id4=5&id5=6", "example.com/?id6=7&id7=8&id8=9", "example.com/?id9=10"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: *I probably need to make a loop for this*. Yes, please add your attempt to the question.

Comment: So loop over and build a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.map` to add `id` to the ids and join the resulting array with `&`

```js
var ids = ["10000000", "2000000", "1234567", "7654321", "7777777"];

var url = "example.com/?" + ids.map((id, ndx) => `id${ndx}=${id}`).join("&");

console.log(url);
```

**EDIT**
Based on the edited question, you can create function to split the array of ids into chunks and use the same code as before, map the chunks to add `id` and join them with `&`

```js
var ids = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "xxx"];

const generateUrls = (ids, n = 3) => {
  var i,
    j,
    temparray,
    urls = [],
    ndx = 0;

  for (i = 0, j = ids.length; i < j; i += n) {
    temparray =
      "example.com/?" +
      ids
        .slice(i, i + n)
        .map(id => `id${ndx++}=${id}`)
        .join("&");
    urls.push(temparray);
  }

  return urls;
};

const result = generateUrls(ids, 3);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I separate it? for example in 3

var ids = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];

and get

var urls= ["example.com/?id0=1&id1=2&id2=3", "example.com/?id3=4&id4=5&id5=6", "example.com/?id6=7&id7=8&id8=9", "example.com/?id9=10"]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was very useful, I just edited the post, with one last question

Comment: One question, how I can fix this?, I'm getting this (example.com/?id0=1&id0=2&id0=3), How i can get this (example.com/?id0=1&id1=2&id2=3). The id1, id2, id3, id4, id5 ,id6, id7... Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking your time, I'm using `+id - 1` but for example if I have this   `var ids = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];` I get this error   `example.com/?idNaN=a&idNaN=b&idNaN=c`